# converting image into matrix and vice versa?

Tags: opencv, c#-4.0

Please tell me how to convert image into matrix of pixels and vice versa...using opencv??

Answer (score 2):

You can treat a matrix or an image as a matrix(or an image) by calling `cvGetMat` (or `cvGetImage`).No data will be copied.
If you want to copy the data, use `cvCopy`.

Comment: Dear Mr. OwnWaterloo, I have an image and I would like to convert it to a matrix. Would I be able to use cvCreateMat instead of cvGetMat? What is the difference?

Comment: IIRC, `cvCreateMat` will allocate both header and data(i.e an **new** matrix). After converting the original image to this matrix by `cvCopy`, change made in one has no effect on the other. On the other hand, `cvGetMat` won't allocate anything, just use its arguments(and be careful with their lifetime). The matrix returned by `cvGetMat` will **share** the data with the original image. BTW: the notification sent by SO escaped my notice, sorry for late...

Comment: Thanks. I understand the difference. No need to apologise, thanks for replying:)